# How does the number of Light bulbs in a series affect the current?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

How does the number of light bulbs in a series circuit affect the current that is going through the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

The more light bulbs you have in a series, the lower the current is. That is because the resistances of the light bulbs add. It is a bit more complicated than with linear resistors (two same resistors in a series have half of the current $I=\frac{U}{2R}$). It is because the resistance of the light bulb changes with the temperature (current) [see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb#Current_and_resistance). For lower current, the resistance is lower. Therefore the current of two light bulbs is going to be less than the current of one light bulb but more than a half of one light bulb.

Comment: Your answer assumes a _constant voltage_ power supply.  The majority of practical circuits are designed to be powered by batteries, or by the power grid, or by a voltage regulated power supply, all of which do a pretty good job of maintaining constant voltage; but not _all_ circuits expect constant voltage.  One modern example would be LED lighting circuits which often are powered by a _constant current_ power supply.  If you have LEDs in series powered by a constant current supply, then adding more LEDs does not change the current:  It makes the voltage go up (to some limit, of course!)